# How to correctly update system ruby version to latest version (2.2.1) on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos

Just trying to update to the latest version of Ruby. On ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#homebrew, I found that you should be able to do it via homebrew:

```
brew install ruby
```

However, when I listed the ruby version (ruby -v) after it 'updated' it was still at the old version 2.0.0.

```
Hermes:~ Sancho$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

I happened to list the contents of /usr/local/bin/ and I could see a symbolic link:

ruby -> ../Cellar/ruby/2.2.1/bin/ruby

So, I don't know what's happening and why the version still lists the old number and not 2.2.1, as it looks like it should.

There are sym links to for various other ruby tools (erb, gem, irb, rake, rdoc, ri) to version 2.2.1 also.

So what is happening here and how do I correctly install version 2.2.1?

I do have RVM installed also, but I want to update the system version of ruby to the latest.

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. Apple put it there for their convenience, not yours, so leave it alone. Instead, install a separate Ruby, either using a sandbox like RVM or rbenv, or using Homebrew.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Homebrew but make sure `/usr/local/bin` is early in your path. Ex:

`.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This will not update the system Ruby version. Instead it will install another version of `ruby` and this line tells `bash` to look for the new version instead.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to upgrade the system version? I would like the system version to be the latest version and then use RVM to use other versions of ruby as required. I would have thought this would be possible.

Comment: @Shantaram I don't use RVM, but theoretically you could try to remove your system ruby and replace it, but this would be a huge hassle and I don't even know if it would work. Usually with OSX system versions you get what you get and you don't get upset

Comment: Ok cool, I'm happy with that. I'll just do as you advise and leave well alone. Thanks for that.

Comment: Removing Apple's Ruby is a bad idea. They have code installed that knows it's supposed to exist there and removing it breaks that code. Just because something is visible to us and we can use it as a user doesn't mean it's there for us to play with. That's true on all OSes. Something to think about.

Comment: @theTinMan correct. Please find attached the link. It does not alter system's ruby version. Rather it creates a virtual environment using rbenv to upgrade the required ruby version. Tried and tested link: https://snyk.io/blog/how-to-install-ruby-in-mac-os/

Answer (score 19):

Easy step

```
brew uninstall ruby # (if installed)
brew install ruby
```

then copy the path and paste into the terminal and restart the terminal
check `ruby --version`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

$PATH doesn't change in [current Terminal session](https://www.pegaxchange.com/2017/06/17/mac-os-x-path-variable/). So please close the Terminal and reopen.

Ref: [Jekyll on macOS](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/)

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://snyk.io/blog/how-to-install-ruby-in-mac-os/) blog. It does not alter system's ruby version. Rather it creates a virtual environment using `rbenv` to upgrade the required ruby version. Tried and tested successfully.